# numpy/scipy/ipython:Failed to interpret file as a pickle

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, ipython

I have the file in following format:

```
0,0.104553357966
1,0.213014562052
2,0.280656379048
3,0.0654249076288
4,0.312223429689
5,0.0959008911106
6,0.114207780917
7,0.105294501195
8,0.0900673766572
9,0.23941317105
10,0.0598239513149
11,0.541701803956
12,0.093929580526
```

I want to plot these point using ipython plot function doing the following:

```
   In [40]: mean_data = load("/Users/daydreamer/data/mean")
```

But it fails saying the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/daydreamer/<ipython-input-40-8f1329559411> in <module>()
----> 1 mean_data = load("/Users/daydreamer/data/mean")

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.6.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-fat3.egg/numpy/lib/npyio.pyc in load(file, mmap_mode)
    354             except:
    355                 raise IOError, \
--> 356                     "Failed to interpret file %s as a pickle" % repr(file)
    357     finally:
    358         if own_fid:

IOError: Failed to interpret file '/Users/daydreamer/data/mean' as a pickle
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: `numpy.load` isn't for loading ascii data.  It's for loading numpy's internal binary format or a pickled numpy array.  You want `numpy.loadtxt` or `numpy.genfromtxt` (the latter handles missing values)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [`numpy.load`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) routine is for loading pickled `.npy` or `.npz` binary files, which can be created using [`numpy.save`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) and [`numpy.savez`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html), respectively. Since you have text data, these are not the routines you want.

You can load your comma-separated values with [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

```
import numpy as np
mean_data = np.loadtxt("/Users/daydreamer/data/mean", delimiter=',')
```

### Full Example

Here's a complete example (using [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) to simulate the file I/O).

```
import numpy as np
import StringIO

s = """0,0.104553357966
1,0.213014562052
2,0.280656379048
3,0.0654249076288
4,0.312223429689
5,0.0959008911106
6,0.114207780917
7,0.105294501195
8,0.0900673766572
9,0.23941317105
10,0.0598239513149
11,0.541701803956
12,0.093929580526"""

st = StringIO.StringIO(s)
a = np.loadtxt(st, delimiter=',')
```

Now we have:

```
>>> a
array([[  0.        ,   0.10455336],
       [  1.        ,   0.21301456],
       [  2.        ,   0.28065638],
       [  3.        ,   0.06542491],
       [  4.        ,   0.31222343],
       [  5.        ,   0.09590089],
       [  6.        ,   0.11420778],
       [  7.        ,   0.1052945 ],
       [  8.        ,   0.09006738],
       [  9.        ,   0.23941317],
       [ 10.        ,   0.05982395],
       [ 11.        ,   0.5417018 ],
       [ 12.        ,   0.09392958]])
```

Comment: maybe you should also indicate, for completness, that load is meant to load pickled `.npy` , or `.npz` binary files.

Comment: @joaquin That is a good suggestion; thank you! I have updated the answer to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: Unbelievable, I was just about to do something just like this and I see someone has already gone through the exact same thing here.  Nice!