# summing the values of a column

Tags: python, numpy

I have an `input` file where first column values are same and other column values are different.
i want to sum  the values of `third` column only(first row to first row...) and want to keep the added values just beside of common first column values.

input

```
> > > >
1.000 3 0.002
2.010 4 -0.001
3.020 5 -0.001
> > > >
1.000 5 0.003
2.010 6 0.005
3.020 6 0.002
```

expected output

```
1.000 0.005
2.010 0.004
3.020 0.001
```

My script

```
import numpy as np
data=np.load("input.txt", allow_pickle=True)
summ=np.sum(data[:,2])
```

Error: Failed to interpret file 'input' as a pickle. Additionally any numpy based solution will be highly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Are those angle brackets `>` present in your input file? This would probably be a lot easier with Pandas.

Comment: yes it is present, i have a solution in pandas but i need to do it using numpy or simple python if possible

Comment: `np.load()` is for pickle files, you want to to use `np.loadtxt()` see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9070381/1560708

Comment: please suggest a complete solution @ShahanM based on numpy only

Comment: Why do you "need" to do it in numpy? Are you aware that Pandas is built on top of numpy?

Comment: You say you have a working solution in Pandas... mind sharing it? In what ways have you struggled to translate the Pandas solution to Numpy?

Comment: @ddejohn it is a part of a long script so other part of script is written fully on numpy libarry so i need it

Comment: @ddejohn as i am new to numpy i get confused...please suggest a solution if possible.

Comment: how many `> > > >` separators are there?

Comment: @enke there are many

Comment: How did you read the data  into in python?

Comment: using numpy.loadtxt @onyambu

Comment: That cannot read the data

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can read only the the first and last columns and `reshape` the array into groups; then `sum`:

```
data = np.loadtxt("input.txt", comments='>', usecols=(0,-1))
length = len(data) // len(np.unique(data[:, 0]))
out = data.reshape(length, -1, 2).sum(axis=0) / [length, 1]
```

Output:

```
array([[1.00e+00, 5.00e-03],
       [2.01e+00, 4.00e-03],
       [3.02e+00, 1.00e-03]])
```

Intermediate step:

```py
>>> data.reshape(length, -1, 2)
array([[[ 1.00e+00,  2.00e-03],
        [ 2.01e+00, -1.00e-03],
        [ 3.02e+00, -1.00e-03]],

       [[ 1.00e+00,  3.00e-03],
        [ 2.01e+00,  5.00e-03],
        [ 3.02e+00,  2.00e-03]]])
```

That said, the whole thing could be a one-liner in pandas:

```py
out = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=' ').pipe(lambda x: x[x.ne('>')].dropna(axis=1, how='all').dropna()).astype('float').groupby('>').sum().reset_index().iloc[:, [0,-1]].to_numpy()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(pd.read_table('input.txt', comment = '>', header = None, sep = ' ').
   groupby(0)[2].sum(1).reset_index().values)

array([[1.00e+00, 5.00e-03],
       [2.01e+00, 4.00e-03],
       [3.02e+00, 1.00e-03]])
```